# Is there a simplified way to express the following function that is defined by two Gauss' hypergeometric functions?

Tags: real-analysis, special-functions, real-numbers, hypergeometric-function, algebra-precalculus

Consider the following function

\begin{align}
f_k(x) = 
   \left( 1 + 2k \left( 1-x^2 \right) \right)
 {}_2 F_1 \left( \tfrac{1}{2} ,k+\tfrac{1}{2}; k+\tfrac{3}{2}; x^2 \right) - 2(k+1) \, {}_2 F_1 \left( -\tfrac{1}{2} ,k+\tfrac{1}{2}; k+\tfrac{3}{2}; x^2 \right)  \, , 
\end{align}
where $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in [0,1]$. 
Here, ${}_2 F_1$ denotes Gauss' hypergeometric function.

For instance, it can be shown that
\begin{align}
f_0 (x) &= -(1-x^2)^{-1/2} \, , \\
f_1(x)  &= \frac{3}{x^3} \left( (1-x^2)\arcsin(x) - x(1-x^2)^\frac{1}{2} \right) \, , 
\end{align}

i was wondering whether a closed form expression in terms of usual functions can be obtained for general value of $k$.

Any thoughts or hints are most welcome.

Thank you

Comment: "i was wondering whether a closed form expression in terms of usual functions can be obtained for general value of n." -- Minor typo, I think you meant for general values of $k$ (unless I completely misunderstood).

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Thanks. Typo corrected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I calculated that if $\,y:=\sqrt{1-x^2},\,$ then
$\, f_0(x) = -y\,$ and for $\,k>0\,$
$$ f_k(x) = \frac{y}{2^{2k-1}(k-1)!x^{2k+1}}
\left(y\sin^{-1}(x)\frac{(2k+1)!}{k!} + 
 2^k P_k(x) \right) $$
where
$$ P_k(x) = (2k+1)!!\left(-x + \sum_{i=1}^{k-1}x^{2i+1}
2^{2i-1}\frac{i!(i-1)!}{(2i+1)!}\right) $$
is a polynomial in powers of $\,x\,$ 
of degree $\,2k-1\,$ with integer coefficients.

I used this Wolfram Mathematica code to check:

```
F[k_,a_] := Hypergeometric2F1[a/2, k+1/2, k+3/2, x^2];
f[k_] := (1+2k(1-x^2))F[k, 1] - 2(k+1)F[k, -1] // Simplify;
P[k_] := (2k+1)!!(-x + Sum[x^(2i+1)2^(2i-1)
    i!(i-1)!/(2i+1)!, {i, 1, k-1}];
y = Sqrt[1-x^2]; myf[0] = -y;
myf[k_] := y(y ArcSin[x](2k+1)!/k! +
    2^k P[k])/(2^(2k-1)(k-1)!x^(2k+1)) // Simplify;
```

Comment: Good work. Thanks a lot

Comment: Nice. Taking $k=1$ in your above equation does not seem to recover the correct expression. The coefficients becomes quickly very large even for $k=2$. Is there a problem in your equation? Thanks for helping

Comment: @Volterra Oops! I made a few mistakes. I have corrected them and the Wolfram code checks now.

Comment: Yes, i have checked your formulas on both Mathematica and Maple. They work fine. Thanks for helping